# Error: Command "npm next build" exited with 1 BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm next build" exited with 1

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, vercel

[image]

I want to deploy my Nextjs Reactjs app to Vercel but the deployment keep failing. It had mooore errors than this previously but this error got me stuck too long. I've already add CI = false in my .env file and environment variable on Vercel, overrode install to add npm i --force, I also already deleted node modules and reinstalled, I've looked in google but this error seems like new and not many discussed yet. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am getting a similar error

Comment: @nasaa unfortunately not yet. i haven't continued debugging it

Comment: I am also getting this error because i had webpack option as a function in next config

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.